# How does electromagnetic polarizer work?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

How does a wire grid polarizer block off electromagnetic waves? Which direction is blocked off? Is it the electric field or magnetic field that is blocked?

Let's use this diagram from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wire-grid-polarizer.svg

The dark red line seems to be the direction that is transmitted and it is perpendicular to the direction of the wires? And if I'm not wrong the direction of polarization refers to the E field.

Comment: Any reference is also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Consider a wave reflecting off a metal surface. Now imagine the charges could only move in one direction.

Comment: It is individual photons that make it through the polarizer or don’t make it through. If any part of a photon hits one of the grids it will be absorbed but if it makes it through it will rotate to become polarized parallel with the grids and continue on its way.

Comment: @user253751 I am imagining that the electric field parallel to the wires drives the oscillation of the free charge in the wires. Are you saying that it's a reflection? Also are we able to compare the thickness of the wire to some length scale? (I can only think of the wavelength of the EM wave.)

Comment: @BillAlsept Thanks for your comment. Could you elaborate on the mechanism that causes the polarization of those photons which made it through to rotate parallel with the grid?

Comment: @Bio Similar to electrons going through a Stern Gerlach experiment where their spins rotate to align with the magnetic field as they travel through. Photons will rotate to align with the polarizer grid or the edges of a slit etc.

Comment: @Bio I view it as a reflection but with the polarization of the reflection constrained to be on one axis. So it only cancels out one axis and the other passes through. Meanwhile Bill is talking about photons - does anyone actually consider photons at the kind of RF frequencies where you might construct a wire grid polarizer?

Comment: @user253751 They should only consider photons going through the grid or slits. You can derive any solution to a light phenomenon using a particle basis. A wave or electromagnetic field can only be explained with billions of individual photons.

Comment: @BillAlsept you probably can, but is it really more convenient?

Comment: @user253751 I don’t think it’s a matter of convenience. Photons can be described. Light waves cannot be described without incorporating billions of coherent photons.